# WF Rules and CodeTypeReferenceExpression

Tags: .net, xml, workflow, designer, rules

I moved some variables into classes in my workflow.

Unfortunately, now the rules fail, I've been trying to set the Type, but keep getting this error.

> Activity 'ifRequestComplete'
>   validation failed: Property
>   "Condition" has invalid value.
>   Condition expression is invalid. The
>   type name specified ("Request,
>   ApprovalWorkflow") can not be
>   resolved.

without the 'ns0:CodeTypeReferenceExpression Type=".."/>' I get this error

> Activity 'ifRequestComplete'
>   validation failed: Property
>   "Condition" has invalid value.
>   Condition expression is invalid. The
>   field "gReq" on type
>   "ApprovalWorkflow.ApprovalFlow" does
>   not exist or is not accessible.

The Request class is created in the ApprovalWorkflow namespace in the same project as the workflow, also named ApprovalWorkflow.

```
namespace ApprovalWorkflow
{
    public class Request    {...}
}
```

the .rules file contains this

```
    <RuleExpressionCondition Name="ifRequestComplete">
        <RuleExpressionCondition.Expression>
            <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression Operator="ValueEquality" xmlns:ns0="clr-namespace:System.CodeDom;Assembly=System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Left>
                    <ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression FieldName="StatusCode">
                        <ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression.TargetObject>
                            <ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression FieldName="gReq">
                                <ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression.TargetObject>
                                    <ns0:CodeTypeReferenceExpression Type="Request, ApprovalWorkflow" />
                                    <ns0:CodeThisReferenceExpression />
                                </ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression.TargetObject>
                            </ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression>
                        </ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression.TargetObject>
                    </ns0:CodeFieldReferenceExpression>
                </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Left>
                <ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right>
                    <ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression>
                        <ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression.Value>
                            <ns1:String xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:System;Assembly=mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">COM</ns1:String>
                        </ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression.Value>
                    </ns0:CodePrimitiveExpression>
                </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.Right>
            </ns0:CodeBinaryOperatorExpression>
        </RuleExpressionCondition.Expression>
    </RuleExpressionCondition>
```

I've tried several different ways of writing the type "Request", "ApprovalWorkflow.Request", "ApprovalWorkflow.Request, ApprovalWorkflow", nothing seems to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, when modifying the underlying objects they changed from fields to properties and the resulting .rules file had to change accordingly.